# Optimization of three dimensional problem where I loop through all items and consider distances to all other items

Tags: loops, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have to consider a three-dimensional space, where elements are evenly distributed. Each element is discribed by three coordinates, x,y and z. I have to calculate the distance between each of those to all of the other, in this way:

```
float distance = 0;
for(int ix = 0; ix<n; ix++) {
    for(int iy = 0; iy<n; iy++) {
        for(int iz = 0; iz<n; iz++) {

            for(int jx = 0; jx<n; jx++) {
                for(int jy = 0; jy<n; jy++) {
                    for(int jz = 0; jz<n; jz++) {
                        distance = distance + calcDistance(ix, iy, iz, jx, jy, jz) / 2
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

For cubes that are over 100 000 items big this takes quite a long time. I divide through two, because each distance is counted twice, but if I can leave out that second calculation, I could maybe double my speed.

In 1 dimension, this is easy. One loop from 0 to n, and another from i to n and I only consider each distance once. But I can't do the same here. Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: Pretty sure there is a formula for it

Answer (score 0):

Cheat. Cheat a lot.

Let's say the "left, top, front" point is `point[0][0][0]` and that's the only point we care about. The point to its right is 1 distance away, the next point to the right is 2 distance away, ... The same "trivial addition" works for the other 2 axis too. You'd only need to calculate distances for diagonals (from `point[0][0][0]` to any other point that isn't in a perfect right/down/back direction).

Once you've got all the distances between `point[0][0][0]` and all other points you can reverse them to find all the distances from all other points to `point[0][0][0]`.

Now... The distance from `point[x1][y1][z1]` to `point[x2][y2][z2]` will be exactly the same as the distance from `point[x1][y1][z1]` to `point[x2][y2][z2]`; and both of these will be exactly the same as the distance from `point[0][0][0]` to `point[x2-x1][y2-y2][z2-z1]`. What this means is that you can use the "distances from `point[0][0][0]`" that you already have (from above) as a lookup table to find all the other distances between all other points; without doing the (assumed much more expensive) `sqrt( (x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1) + (z2-z1)*(z2-z1) ) );` calculation for any of them.

Of course if you are using "distances from `point[0][0][0]`" that you already have (from above) as a lookup table, there's probably no point storing these distances at all. You can just use the values from the lookup table when you need it (without storing it elsewhere).

In other words; I'd be wanting a function like this (in C):

```
static double getDistance( int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2) {
    int dx = abs(x1-x2);
    int dy = abs(y1-y2);
    int dz = abs(z1-z2);
    return distanceTable[dx][dy][dz];
}
```

In this case you'd have to pre-calculate the distance table (which is the "distances from `point[0][0][0]` to every other point" above).

However, if you want to be lazy, it might be more fun to do something like this:

```
static double getDistance( int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2) {
    int dx = abs(x1-x2);
    int dy = abs(y1-y2);
    int dz = abs(z1-z2);
    if(dx+dy+dz == 0) return 0.0;

    double distance = distanceTable[dx][dy][dz];
    if(distance == 0.0) {
        distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
        distanceTable[dx][dy][dz] = distance;
    }
    return distance;
}
```